# What happens when you open a Flask app multiple times on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flask

I have a Flask-Angular application and it is hosted on 127.0.0.1:5000. I opened this link twice on 2 separate tabs. I have a function that uses time.sleep() for 8 seconds when I click a button called "Run".
When I click the Run button on both tabs, I would expect that the first tab sleeps for 8 seconds and the second tab should've been asleep for 16 seconds (asleep 8 seconds and waiting for server while the first app uses the function for another 8 seconds)
However, both the tabs stay asleep for 8 seconds only.
How is this possible?
Is Chrome creating new instances of my back end as well?

Comment: Chrome isn't creating new instances, your server is. It would be really bad if each sleep had to wait for other sleeps before it could continue.

Comment: So is this happening automatically? Because I haven't used session management at all. And will my server continue to create as many instances as requests? Are those instances destroyed later automatically too?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/